# Python:How can I get a float value which interval belongs to?

Tags: python

I have got some interval like (0,1),[1,2),...,[9,10).I want to know a float value,`e.g 3.75`,belongs to which interval.What I did is make a left boundary list `[0,1,...,9]` and a right boundary list `[1,2,...,10]`. And I'll find the first value in left boundary which `3.75` larger than it, `3`.Then find the first value in right boundary which `3.75` smaller than it, `4`.Then `3.75` belongs to interval [3,4).Is there a better way to find which interval `3.75` belongs to?

Answer (score 1):

It's enough to store only one list of boundaries. You can use [`bisect_right`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect_right) find the index of left boundary of the interval and then `index + 1` is the right boundary:

```
import bisect

def find(num, boundaries):
    if boundaries[0] < num < boundaries[-1]:
        index = bisect.bisect_right(boundaries, num)
        return boundaries[index - 1], boundaries[index]
    return None

b = range(11)
CASES = [3.75, 0, 10, 5, 0.1, 9.9, 11, -1, 6.7]

for n in CASES:
    print('{} belongs to group {}'.format(n, find(n, b)))
```

Output:

```
3.75 belongs to group (3, 4)
0 belongs to group None
10 belongs to group None
5 belongs to group (5, 6)
0.1 belongs to group (0, 1)
9.9 belongs to group (9, 10)
11 belongs to group None
-1 belongs to group None
6.7 belongs to group (6, 7)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try using the floor() and ceil() functions in the Python math library to solve your problem.

```
import math
lb = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
ub = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

inp = raw_input('Enter a number : ')
num = float(inp)

term = [[x, y] for x, y in zip(lb, ub) if int(math.floor(num)) == x and        int(math.ceil(num)) == y] 
if term == []:
    print str(num) + ' does not belong to any specified interval'
else:
    print str(num) + ' belongs to the interval ' + str(term[0])
```